# typedef Char* does not name a type

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

I'm facing some kind of problem as a beginner in C++.
I want to specify my own types with pointers. But my code doesn't compile.
Here's a glimpse of what i'm trying to do :

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    typedef os_uchar Boolean;
    typedef Boolean& Boolean_out;
    typedef Boolean* Boolean_ptr;

    [...]
}
```

And i'm getting errors for these lignes :

```
'os_uchar' does not name a type
'Boolean' does not name a type
'Boolean' does not name a type
```

How can I specify Boolean* and Boolean& as defined types ? Is it possible ?

I'd be grateful for your answers :)

Comment: You're saying Boolean should be of type os_uchar, but os_uchar isn't defined as a type itself.

Comment: The error message says everything. What's `os_uchar`? The compiler doesn't know it.

Comment: Boolean is spelt bool in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your errors come from the first one - `'os_uchar' does not name a type`. Simply include the header where the type `os_uchar` is defined and it should work.